# Elasticsearch exclude documents containing specific terms

Tags: java, python, elasticsearch, lucene

I've indexed documents like bellow in `elasticsearch`.

```
{    
    "category": "clothing (f)",
    "description": "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt - Women’s Short Sleeve Shirt",
    "name": "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt",
    "price": "$34.99"
}
```

There are categories like `clothing (m)`, `clothing (f)` etc. I am trying to exclude the `cloting (m)` category items if the search is for female items. The query I am trying is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "description": "women's black shirt"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "category": "clothing (m)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50
}
```

But this is not working as expected. There are always few results with `clothing (m)` document with other documents. How can I exclude documents which have a particular category?

Answer (score 2):

In order to exclude a specific `term` (exact match) you will have to use `keyword` datatype.

> Keyword datatypes are typically used for filtering (Find me all blog posts where status is published), for sorting, and for aggregations. Keyword fields are only searchable by their **exact value**.

[Keyword Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)

Your current query catches **clothing (m)** in the results because when you indexed your documents they were analyzed with elasticsearch `standard` analyzer which analyzes  **clothing (m)** as **clothing**  and **(m)**.

In your query you searched for `category` as `text` datatype.

> Text datatype fields are analyzed, that is they are passed through an analyzer to convert the string into a list of individual terms before being indexed.

Run this command:

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "text": ["clothing (m)"]
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "clothing",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "m",
      "start_offset" : 10,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

A working example:

Assuming you mappings look like that:

```
{
 "my_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "category" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "description" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "price" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's post a few documents:

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
{    
    "category": "clothing (m)",
    "description": "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt - Women’s Short Sleeve Shirt",
    "name": "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt",
    "price": "$34.99"
}


POST my_index/_doc/2
{    
    "category": "clothing (f)",
    "description": "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt - Women’s Short Sleeve Shirt",
    "name": "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt",
    "price": "$34.99"
}
```

Now our query should look like this:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "description": "women's black shirt"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "category.keyword": "clothing (m)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50
}
```

The results:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.43301374,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.43301374,
        "_source" : {
          "category" : "clothing (f)",
          "description" : "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt - Women’s Short Sleeve Shirt",
          "name" : "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt",
          "price" : "$34.99"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Results without using `keyword`

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.43301374,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.43301374,
        "_source" : {
          "category" : "clothing (f)",
          "description" : "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt - Women’s Short Sleeve Shirt",
          "name" : "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt",
          "price" : "$34.99"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.43301374,
        "_source" : {
          "category" : "clothing (m)",
          "description" : "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt - Women’s Short Sleeve Shirt",
          "name" : "Women's Unstoppable Graphic T-Shirt",
          "price" : "$34.99"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see from the last results we got also **clothing (m)**.
BTW don't use `term` for `text` datatype. use `match`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not excluding the terms in all cases.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Not getting the expected result

Comment: Do you want to give an example of "Not getting the expected result "? cause my example is working.

Comment: Yes it worked for me for a while too. But I am getting data of the keyword that I excluded. So this is certainly not the solution.

Comment: I updated my query (using filter). Filters  will not influence scoring. try it.